# javascript DOM manipulation and removing event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the code, I'm trying to add some elements to the body dynamically using javascript and assigning some `event Listener`s to it. Once the page reloads, I want to remove all the event listeners from the elements I have added dynamically .
I have tried some methods but couldn't get the desired output. Any suggestion will be appreciated

```js
// function to check whether enter is pressed or not will be loaded on load
function check(){
    var newItemInputBox = document.getElementById("newToDoItem");
 newItemInputBox.addEventListener("keydown",function keyCheck(key){
  if(key.keyCode === 13){
   // 13 is the keycode for enter
   var newItem = newItemInputBox.value;
   console.log("Enter key pressed");
   console.log("the entered item is "+newItemInputBox.value);
   if(newItem == null||newItem == ""){
    alert("Please enter valid ToDO name");
    console.log("No item was present in the text box");
   } else {
       letsAddNewItem();
   }
  }      
 });     
}

// function to add new Items to the item container
function letsAddNewItem(){
 var newItemInputBox = document.getElementById("newToDoItem");
 var itemName = newItemInputBox.value;
 newItemInputBox.value = null;
 
 //creating referance to ul element
 var container = document.getElementById("itemContainerId");
 
 //creating a list element
 var listItem = document.createElement("LI");
 
 //creating a label with the name input by the user
 var label = document.createElement("label");
 label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(itemName));
 
 //creating a checkbox
 var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
 checkBox.type = "checkbox";
 checkBox.id = "checkBoxId";

 //changing checkbox label status to striked out look or to normal
 checkBox.onclick = changeState(checkBox,label);
 
 //creating horizontal rule
 var horizontalRule = document.createElement("HR");
 
 //creating delete button
 var deleteButton = document.createElement("A");
 deleteButton.href = "#";
 deleteButton.id = "deleteButtonId"
 deleteButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
 deleteButton.classList.add("deleteButtonStyle");

 //adding onclick listener to the delete button
 deleteButton.onclick = function deleteAllElements(){
  container.removeChild(listItem);
  console.log("Item has been deleted after pressing delete button");
 }
 
 
 //adding everything to list item, i.e li element
 listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
 console.log("checkbox added to the list");
 listItem.appendChild(label);
 console.log("label added to the list");
 listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
 console.log("Delete button added to the list");
 listItem.appendChild(horizontalRule);
 console.log("Horizontal rule added to the list");
 
 //adding li element to the container, i.e ul element
 container.appendChild(listItem);
 console.log("Whole list item is added to the ul element");
}

function changeState(checkBox,label){
 if(checkBox.checked){
   label.classList.add("strikeItOut");
   console.log("Striked out look added");
  } else{
   label.classList.remove("strikeItOut");
   console.log("normal look added");
  }
}

function removeEverything(){
 // will be called onunload
 console.log("Removing everything now");    
}
```

Comment: I don't really get what you want. When the page reloads all events (and everything else) are removed anyway.

Comment: the point is, you should know what elements you want to target and everything else will go through. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener